# How many input bits do current processors take?

Tags: hardware, processor

I was wondering how many bits of information can flow into the processor in one CPU cycle?

I found the socket information (for my i7: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1366) but there is no word on the actual amount of data that is sent to the processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The front side bus protocol for that socket is called [Intel QuickPath Interconnect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_QuickPath_Interconnect). The article says that

> The basic unit of transfer is the 80-bit "flit", which is transferred in two clock cycles (four 20 bit transfers, two per clock.) The 80-bit "flit" has 8 bits for error detection, 8 bits for "link-layer header," and 64 bits for data.

You'll find in general, the situation with modern interconnect protocols is more complicated than a certain number of bits being transferred per clock cycle. For instance, in protocols that go through cables (Ethernet, for example), they will scramble the data so that the average of the 1s and 0s over enough time is 1/2 (for electrical reasons), which involves sending 10 bits for every 8 bits of actual data.

Additionally, with QPI, the interface is wide enough to be divided up as the processor sees fit:

> Although the initial implementations use single four-quadrant links, the QPI specification permits other implementations. Each quadrant can be used independently.